# How to return the partitioned matrix?

Tags: c

The following code:

```
Divide(int A[4][4],int n,int position)
{
    int i,j,Partition[2][2];
    //Top left
    if(position==1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n/2;j++)
            {
                Partition[i][j]=A[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    //Top right
    else if(position==2)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n/2;j++)
            {
                Partition[i][j]=A[i][j+n/2];
            }
        }
    }
    //Bottom left
    else if(position==3)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n/2;j++)
            {
                Partition[i][j]=A[i+n/2][j];
            }
        }
    }
    //Bottom right
    else if(position==4)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n/2;j++)
            {
                Partition[i][j]=A[i+n/2][j+n/2];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",Partition[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return Partition;
}
int main()
{
    int A[4][4] = {
        {2,3,4,5},
        {3,4,5,6},
        {4,5,6,7},
        {5,3,7,8},
    };

    int C[4][4]; //= {0};


    C[2][2]=Divide(A,4,1);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

gives logical error when I try to print the partitioned matrix after returning it. But the *divide* function works perfectly fine. I'm a beginner I think I am wrong in this part:

```
int C[4][4];
    C[2][2]=Divide(A,4,1);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Hope you can get through my problem. Help will be much appreciated :)
Here's the output I'm getting: (changing some values gives errors, so I'm posting this)

```
2 3
3 4
4199744 0
0 0
```

Comment: This code should have produced warnings that should be fixed.  Since no return type is declared for `Divide`, it implicitly returns an `int`.  So when it tries to return `Partition`, it is attempting to return a pointer type, which is cast to an `int`.  That's a serious bug.  But the real problem seems to stem from a fundamental misconception about array assignments vs. initializations.  `C[2][2] = Divide(A,4,1);` calls `Divide`, which returns a pointer that has been cast to an `int`.  It then stores that useless `int` value in `C[2][2]`, leaving the other elements of `C` unchanged.

Comment: Please elaborate "logical error".

Comment: Please elaborate "the divide function works perfectly fine". What test cases did you try? What ist their result? What is the purpose of that function? If you describe it, we might be able to follow your assertion.

Comment: "I think I am wrong in this part", what makes you think so?

Comment: "Here's the output I'm getting: (changing some values gives errors, so I'm posting this)" So that is an example of correct output? What are examples of incorrect output? How are they incorrect?

Comment: Instead of trying to make `Divide` return an array, you want to pass a pointer to the array, and have `Divide` fill in the array referenced by the pointer.  That's how this is done.

Comment: Is this question describing/defining the purpose of your function? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68077725/7733418

Comment: Okk, I get it, thanks @TomKarzes I now get the concept. But for the code part did you meant we can only return it using pointers? I mean what could be the other ways?

Comment: @Younnosch, the logical error was when I printed it from main function. The divide function is correct because printing values form inside it gives what expected. It's halfway correct ;)

Comment: @TomKarzes @Yunnosch Thanks a lot to u guys for the help. Here's the solution I got ```int **C;

    C=Divide(A,4,2);

    Divide(A,4,2);


    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)

    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)

        {

           printf("%d ",C[i][j]);

        }

        printf("\n");
    }```     I still want to know other possible ways.

Comment: @Yunnosch Both are kinda similar but this one is just solely for partitioning, so u can say both are independent. I dont know if I'm going to use this function for that and vice versa.

Comment: Please turn your solution comment into an answer. After a little time you can even accept your own answer.

Comment: If you say so ;)

Comment: If you somehow got this code to compile, you have much bigger problems than how to implement this function. Your compiler is either completely outdated by > 20 years or configured in bad ways.

Comment: @Lundin o.O Didnt get you

Comment: `Divide(int A[4][4],int n,int position)` isn't valid C. Also, you need to study how arrays work.

Comment: @Lundin Will do for sure

Answer (score 1):

Few things which might surprise you:

- In C, an expression that has type *array of type* is converted to an expression with type *pointer to type* (with few exceptions) that points to the initial element of the array object.
- In C, you cannot return an array from a function because, when you try to return an array, as per the above rule, the array name in the return statement will be converted to pointer and function end up returning that pointer.

In this statement

```
return Partition;
```

the `Partition` will be converted to pointer to an object which is an array of `2` integers. So, `Divide()` function end up returning a pointer of type `int (*)[2]`. Note that `Partition` array is a local variable of `Divide()` function, it's  scope and life limited to `Divide()` function. That means, once the `Divide()` function returned, `Partition` array no more exists and accessing it will result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

One possible solution could be - allocate memory to `Partition` dynamically, as per your need, and return the pointer from `Divide()` function. With this you have to explicitly take care of freeing the dynamically allocated memory once you done with it.

You can do:

```
int ** Divide (int A[4][4], int n, int position)
{
    int i, j;
    int **Partition = malloc (sizeof (int *) * 2); 
    if (Partition == NULL) {
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        Partition[i] = malloc (sizeof (int) * 2);
        if (Partition[i] == NULL) {
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    // rest of the code.....

    return Partition;
}
```

and, in `main()`, make sure the variable which is receiving `Divide()` function returned value should have same type as that of `Divide()` function return type:

```
    int ** C = Divide (A,4,1);
```

make sure to free the dynamically allocated memory once done with it in `main()`, like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        free (C[i]);
    }
    free (C);
```

Other possible solution could be - declare `Partition` array as `static`. The lifetime of a static variable is the entire run of the program. You can access the static variable outside of its scope as well if you have the address of that static variable. Remember, if static variable declared within scope of function, its value persist between that function calls.

If you make `Partition` array static, the `Divide()` function return type should be `int (*)[2]`:

```
int (* Divide(int A[4][4], int n, int position))[2] {
    static int Partition[2][2];

    // rest of the code.....

    return Partition;
}
```

In the above code, `Divide()` function return type is a pointer to an object which is an array of `2` integer because that's what the `Partition` will be converted to. *[If you don't get it then read the declaration of `Divide()` function using [Clockwise/Spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)]*

To make it more readable, we can use `typedef`:

```
typedef int(*Type)[2];

Type Divide (int A[4][4],int n,int position)
{
    static int Partition[2][2];

    // rest of the code.....

    return Partition;
}
```

In the `main()`, the type of `C` should be `int (*)[2]`, declare it like this:

```
int (*C)[2];
C = Divide (A,4,1);
```

Or, if you are using `typedef` then you can do:

```
Type C = Divide (A,4,1);
```

---

**Additional**:
If you do not specify return type of a function, C will implicitly declare it as `int`. If you are using a compiler targeting C99 or later standard of C, you will get a warning similar like this, if you omit a function return type:

```
warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
```

Comment: It's important to realize that the warning comes from writing invalid C code. So it's not just some "hey when you have time maybe check out this little issue" message, but rather a "your code is broken and doesn't follow the language specification" message. Additionally, no version of C has ever allowed implicit conversion from arrays to int, or from a pointer type to int, so that's also a so called "constraint violation" of the C language.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning an array of arrays, you can pass a pointer as an argument of the function, so that you could rewrite your program into something like the following

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum position_in_matrix {
    pos_top_left, pos_top_right, pos_bottom_left, pos_bottom_right
};

void Divide( int n, int A[n][n]           // VLA notation, requires at least C99
           , enum position_in_matrix pos
           , int P[n/2][n/2] )
{
    int row_0 = pos == pos_top_left  ||  pos == pos_top_right
              ? 0 : n/2;
    int col_0 = pos == pos_top_left  ||  pos == pos_bottom_left
              ? 0 : n/2;

    for(int i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n/2; ++j)
        {
            P[i][j] = A[row_0 + i][col_0 + j];
        }
    }
}

void print_mat(int n, int m[n][n])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            printf("%3d",m[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int A[4][4] = {
        {2,3,4,5},
        {3,4,5,6},
        {4,5,6,7},
        {5,3,7,8},
    };
    print_mat(4, A);
    putchar('\n');
    int C[2][2];
    Divide(4, A, pos_top_left, C);
    print_mat(2, C);
    putchar('\n');
    Divide(4, A, pos_top_right, C);
    print_mat(2, C);
    putchar('\n');
    Divide(4, A, pos_bottom_left, C);
    print_mat(2, C);
    putchar('\n');
    Divide(4, A, pos_bottom_right, C);
    print_mat(2, C);
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Th9T8n8n5).

If you still want to return an object, consider writing a proper abstract data type represented by some `struct`.

Comment: Will try. Thanks for this.